# Sending explicit intent doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I want to send explicit intent from `Service` with specified component to `Activity`. I have defined `BroadcastReceiver` dynamically in `MainActivity.java`.

When I don't set component for `Intent`, it is received in the activity. But with specified component then it doesn't work. Why is it?

*BroadcastService.java*:

```
public class BroadcastService extends IntentService {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent();
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName(
                MainActivity.class.getPackage().getName(),
                MainActivity.class.getName());
        intent.setComponent(component);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        intent.putExtra("time", new Date().toLocaleString());
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.java*:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateUI(intent);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation of `Intent.setComponent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setComponent%28android.content.ComponentName%29) says:

> (Usually optional) Explicitly set the component to handle the intent. If left with the default value of null, the system will determine the appropriate class to use based on the other fields (action, data, type, categories) in the Intent. If this class is defined, the specified class will always be used regardless of the other fields. You should only set this value when you know you absolutely want a specific class to be used; otherwise it is better to let the system find the appropriate class so that you will respect the installed applications and user preferences.

But you're doing:

```
intent = new Intent();
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(
        MainActivity.class.getPackage().getName(),
        MainActivity.class.getName());
intent.setComponent(component);
```

That means you set a component which points to `MainActivity`, not the broadcast receiver inside the `MainActivity`, hence it doesn't work.

To fix, you can move your inner broadcast receiver to a separate class. But if so, you can't interact with the controls in `MainActivity`. There are many other ways to archive your goal. I suggest [`ResultReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html) (available in API 3+). When starting your service, you put a `ResultReceiver` into the intent. When the service wants to send information to the activity, you do it via the `ResultReceiver` given.

Comment: Thanks. I don't perceive that the intent is sended to the `MainActivity` and the broadcast receiver doesn't catch it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about the ResultReceiver. I'm astonished I had never heard of such a useful class before!

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot send explicit broadcast or explicit intent – first check the ComponentName. the package name must be the application ID and not the package name you can see in your receiver class.

Look for the application id in build.gradle:

```
             defaultConfig {
                            applicationId "com.my.app.id.name"
```

or in  auto generated buildConfig.java file after build:

app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\release\

```
             package com.my.app.id.name;
```

For example if your class name is “MyExplicitReciver”
and the package name you can see in the first line of this class is

```
            package com.my.app.myPackage.name.receivers;
```

so the class name should be :
                 com.my.app.myPackage.name.receivers.MyExplicitReciver

and you should set compoonent name like this in setComponent:

```
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.my.app.id.name",
    "com.my.app.myPackage.name.receivers.MyExplicitReciver"));
            context().sendBroadcast(intent);
```